# Permission denied, error log

Tags: php, error-handling, logging

I'm trying to create a simple error log that write down php errors in case these cannot be reported to the admin (with a database connection). I wrote this:

```
function errorLog($array)
{
    $time = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $no = $array['e-no'];
    $string = $array['e-string'];
    $file = $array['e-file'];
    $line = $array['e-line'];
    $context = $array['e-context'];

    $string = "TIME {$time} IP {$ip} ERROR {$no} | {$string} | {$file} | {$line} | {$context}";
    if ($handler = fopen('log/log-file.txt', 'a'))
    {
        fwrite($handler, $string);
        fclose($handler);
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Fatal Error #0002');
    }
}
```

**START EDIT**

Function had became

```
function errorLog($array)
{
    $time = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $type = $array['e-type'];
    $string = $array['e-string'];
    $file = $array['e-file'];
    $line = $array['e-line'];
    $context = $array['e-context']
    $string = "ON {$time} IP {$ip} ERROR {$type} | {$string} | {$file} | {$line} | {$context}"; 
    if (!error_log($string, 3, 'log/log-file.txt')) { exit('Fatal Error #0002'); }
}
```

**END EDIT**

But when i run it i get

```
Warning: fopen(log/log-file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in myfile.php on line 17
```

I got this is a server permission problem, but i am working on a localhost (Xampp on Mac os x) and i'd like to manage these permissions. How can i place log/ to be writable only? Is there any better ways of doing what i am trying to do?

Comment: Not a sollution to your current problem, but you might want to read up on the function error_log. that might simplify your code a bit?

Comment: create that log file by your ftp client and set 666 permissions for it

Comment: can't you use absolute path and use a folder that apache has permission to write?

Comment: Make sure the user executing the script has permission to write the error log file. If you're running this from a browser then the Apache (nobody or www-data) would be the user which has limited permissions t write. If you're running this from the command line or CRON, double check the file permissions as well as the file path as with each user that executes the script their home path would change.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, answer this question and you will get the accepted answer since your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I got this is a server permission problem, but i am working on a localhost (Xampp on Mac os 
>   x) and i'd like to manage these permissions. How can i place log/ to be writable only? Is 
>   there any better ways of doing what i am trying to do?

You might want to checkout [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), to make sure all errors are automatically sent through your custom function. Anyway, that's not the source of your problem, your issue is actually the permissions on the server. Now, the first thing to do is to determine as what user PHP is running. This can be very simple to determine, you just have to run this script:

```
<?php
echo `whoami`;
```

In case of your Mac, that probably is 'www-data'. If you want to change that (possibly), you should delve into how (f.e.) [Apache MPM ITK](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net) works. If you're fine with 'www-data' running your scripts, you should give 'www-data' access to the log directory. First, go to the parent directory and issue command 'ls -laF', to see detailed information about the log directory. Let's say the output is the following:

rwxr-xr-x   2 berry berry      4096 2011-01-18 16:53 log/

In this case, I (the user "berry") would be the owner. The group that I'm primarily in (namely, "berry") is the group that owns the directory. Now, you can tell by the rwx r-x r-x, that the owner (first rwx) can read, write and execute. The second (the group) can read and execute. The others (everyone else) can read and execute.

"www-data" is probably not in the group "berry". To fix this, you want to issue the command: `chgrp -R www-data log/`, followed by `chmod -R g+x log/`. That means: change the owning group to "www-data", and give the group (g) execute permission (+x), do that recursively (-R) on directory "log/".

Good luck.

Comment: I appreciated this answer but i solved my problem by just creating that file and giving it the 666 permission. By the way, this answer could be usefull to everybody, so i'll accept it.

Comment: Isn't the proper call "echo exec('whoami');"?

Comment: @Andrija Depends on what you call proper. Backticks and exec will have the same result.

Comment: I meant that the echo 'whoami' didn't work for me (probably a server confing thing) and exec did; it seems to me that exec is more "configuration-proof".

Comment: @Andrija It's echo `whoami`, in backticks, not normal single quotes.

Comment: If you are using nginx+phpfpm, the php interpreter is actually running as nobody:nogroup. You must change the location to be written same as nobody:nogroup or downgrade the permission to everyone level.